# Why are there so many `map` function for different types in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I'm learning F#. I started FP with Haskell, and I've got curious for this.

Since F# is .NET language, It seems to be more reasonable for me to declare interface like `Mappable`, just like haskell `Functor` type class.

[image]

But like the picture above, F# functions are seperated and implemented on it's own. What's the design purpose of such design? For me, introducing `Mappable.map` and implementing this for each data type would be more convenient.

Comment: This question does not belong on SO. It is not a programming problem. I suggest you ask in F# Slack or some other discussion forum.

Comment: @BentTranberg Generously read, `The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.` would also encompass language design questions, as long as the other criteria are fulfilled.

Comment: Long story short, F# does not have type classes, and therefore needs to reimplement ``map`` and other common higher order function for each collection type. An interface would help little since it still requires each collection type to provide a separate implementation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, a very straightforward question on the surface. But if you take the time to think it through to the end, you get into the depths of type theory immeasurable. And the type theory stares also into you.

First, of course, you have already correctly figured out that F# doesn't have type classes, and that's why. But you propose an interface `Mappable`. Ok, let's look into that.

Let's say we can declare such an interface. Can you imagine what the signature of it would look like?

```
type Mappable =
    abstract member map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'f<'a> -> 'f<'b>
```

Where `f` is the type implementing the interface. Oh wait! F# doesn't have that either! Here `f` is a  higher-kinded type variable, and F# doesn't have higher-kindedness at all. There is no way to declare a function `f : 'm<'a> -> 'm<'b>` or something like that.

But ok, let's say we got over that hurdle as well. And now we have an interface `Mappable` that can be implemented by `List`, `Array`, `Seq`, and the kitchen sink. But wait! Now we have a *method* instead of a function, and methods don't compose well! Let's look at adding 42 to every element of a nested list:

```
// Good ol' functions:
add42 nestedList = nestedList |> List.map (List.map ((+) 42))

// Using an interface:
add42 nestedList = nestedList.map (fun l -> l.map ((+) 42))
```

Look: now we have to use a lambda expression! There is no way to pass this `.map` implementation to another function as a value. Effectively the end of "functions as values" (and yes, I know, using a lambda doesn't look very bad in this example, but trust me, it gets very ugly)

But wait, we're still not done. Now that it's a method call, type inference doesn't work! Because a .NET method's type signature depends on the type of the object, there is no way for the compiler to infer both. This is actually a very common problem newbies hit when interoperating with .NET libraries. And the only cure is to provide a type signature:

```
add42 (nestedList : #Mappable) = nestedList.map (fun l -> l.map ((+) 42))
```

Oh, but this is still not enough! Even though I have provided a signature for `nestedList` itself, I have not provided a signature for the lambda's parameter `l`. What should such signature be? Would you say it should be `fun (l: #Mappable) -> ...` ? Oh, and now we finally got to rank-N types, for you see, `#Mappable` is a shortcut for "any type `'a` such that `'a :> Mappable`" - i.e. a lambda expression which is itself generic.

Or, alternatively, we could go back to the higher-kindedness and declare the type of `nestedList` more precisely:

```
add42 (nestedList : 'f<'a<'b>> where 'f :> Mappable, 'a :> Mappable) = ...
```

But ok, let's put aside the type inference for now and get back to the lambda expression and how we now cannot pass `map` as a value to another function. Let's say we extend the syntax a bit to allow for something like what Elm does with record fields:

```
add42 nestedList = nestedList.map (.map ((+) 42))
```

What would the type of `.map` be? It would have to be a *constrainted* type, just like in Haskell!

```
.map : Mappable 'f => ('a -> 'b) -> 'f<'a> -> 'f<'b>
```

Wow, ok. Putting aside the fact that .NET doesn't even allow such types to exist, effectively we just got back type classes!

But there is a reason that F# doesn't have type classes in the first place. Many aspects of that reason are described above, but a more concise way to put it is: *simplicity*.

For you see, this is a ball of yarn. Once you have type classes, you have to have constraints, higher-kindedness, rank-N (or at least rank-2), and before you know it, you're asking for impredicative types, type functions, GADTs, and all the rest of it.

But Haskell does pay a price for all the goodies. Turns out there is no good way to *infer* all that stuff. Higher-kinded types sorta work, but constraints already kinda don't. Rank-N - don't even dream of it. And even when it works, you get type errors that you have to have a PhD to understand. And that's why in Haskell you're gently *encouraged* to put type signatures on everything. Well, not *everything*-everything, but really almost everything. And where you don't put type signatures (e.g. inside `let` and `where`) - surprise-surprise, those places are actually monomorphised, so you're essentially back in the simplistic F#-land.

In F#, on the other hand, type signatures are rare, mostly just for documentation or for .NET interop. Outside of those two cases, you can write a whole big complex program in F# and not use a type signature once. Type inference works fine, because there is nothing too complex or ambiguous for it to handle.

And this is the big advantage of F# over Haskell. Yes, Haskell lets you express super complex stuff in a very precise way, that's good. But F# lets you be very wishy-washy, almost like Python or Ruby, and still have the compiler catch you if you stumble.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you!
It would be nice to have few words about why the following would not be a valid workaround:

type Mappable<'a> =
    abstract member map : ('a -> 'b) -> Mappable<'a> -> Mappable<'b>

Comment: This way you lose the knowledge of what container it is. You can no longer do anything with it expect map it again.